# addEventListener só funciona uma vez

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de recriação ao site oficial da Apple (intuito apenas de estudos). Estou criando o menu responsivo e resolvi acrescentar JavaScript para isso.

O código é esse:

```
const menu_bars = document.getElementById('menu_bars')
const menu = document.getElementById('menu')

menu_bars.addEventListener('click', menu_responsivo)

function menu_responsivo() {
   menu.style.height = '100%'

   menu_bars.addEventListener('click', () => {
         menu.style.height = '50px'
      })
}
```

[Quando clico no icon bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhX28.png)

[Menu normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNo89.png)

Ele funciona bem, com transition pelo CSS, bem bonito, porém, ele funciona apenas uma vez. Como posso fazer que `addEventListener` funcione várias vezes?

Comment: `menu_bars.addEventListener('click'` dentro de `menu_responsivo` acaba por sobreescrever o evento, por isso funciona somente uma vez.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Conforme comentado pelo Cmte Cardeal, o *listener* que você colocou dentro da função `menu_responsivo` sobrescreve o *listener* que está fora dela, por isso a animação só está funcionando uma vez.

O ideal na maioria dos casos, incluindo esse, é definir os estilos no próprio CSS, e não no JavaScript. Você pode ter uma classe `open` que irá aplicar o CSS quando seu menu for aberto. O JavaScript se encarregaria apenas de adicionar e remover essa classe de `menu` quando `menu_bars` for clicado. Para isso, você só precisa de um *listener*.

CSS

```
#menu {
    height: 50px;
}

#menu.open {
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
const menu_bars = document.getElementById('menu_bars')
const menu = document.getElementById('menu')

menu_bars.addEventListener('click', menu_responsivo)

function menu_responsivo() {
    menu.classList.toggle('open')
}
```

Comment: obrigado. deu certo!